# Can I use css/js from dependent module drupal?

Tags: javascript, css, web, drupal

I have two modules on Drupal 7. I want to make dependent module load css/js files from other module.

Parent module info:

```
name = mymodule
description = ParentModule
core = 7.x
version = «7.x-1.0»
configure = admin/config/content/mymodule
files[] = mymodule.module
scripts[] = mymodule.js
stylesheets[all][] = css/main.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/mobile.css
```

Dependent module info:

```
name = mysecondmodule
description = DependentModule
dependencies[] = mymodule ; here I inject dependences
core = 7.x
version = «7.x-1.0»
configure = admin/config/content/mysecondmodule
```

Main module is dependent. All what I want, to create "parent" module, that will contain only css files (and nothing else) that could be loaded from my main and other modules. I know the best way is Themes, but I need that.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, Drupal shows that mysecondmodule is dependent. So if there isn't mymodule, there will be notification about that.
Therefore, at dependent module info we can add following:

```
name = mysecondmodule
description = DependentModule
dependencies[] = mymodule ; here I inject dependences
core = 7.x
version = «7.x-1.0»
configure = admin/config/content/mysecondmodule
stylesheets[all][] = ../mymodule/css/main.css   ; relative path to "parent" module
stylesheets[all][] = ../mymodule/css/mobile.css ;
```